# Magento 2 Check if url returns 404

Tags: magento2.2.2, geturl, http-error-404, http-header

I have ann Array of urls

```
$arr = Array(
       'http://magento2.com/url-exist',
       'http://magento2.com/url-does-not-exist',
       'http://magento2.com/url-does-not-exist',
       'http://magento2.com/url-exist');
```

I've tried curl, get_headers they all failed

output is wrong:

```
<a href="http://magento2.com/url-exist" >Link-1</a>
<a href="http://magento2.com/url-does-not-exist" >Link-2</a>
<a href="http://magento2.com/url-does-not-exist" >Link-3</a>
<a href="http://magento2.com/url-exist" >Link-4</a>
```

It should return only url 1 and 4 **200** status code e.g:

```
<a href="http://magento2.com/url-exist" >Link-1</a>
<a href="http://magento2.com/url-exist" >Link-4</a>
```

However it's returning all **200** but 2 and 3 should return **404**

Anyone have any idea why ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you go to `http://magento2.com/url-does-not-exist` you get 404 ?

Comment: @prince Absolutely correct this url : **http://magento2.com/url-does-not-exist**  returns 404

Comment: So what is the issue if this url doesn't realy exist ?

Comment: @PRINCE using I am looping the array to check status code using `get_headers()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) it shouldn't return all 200  if returns 404 then I don't include the link in the markup

Answer (score 0):

1. `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`, `php bin/magento cache:clean`
2. ```
   <?php
   $arr = Array(
       "link 1" => 'http://magento2.com/url-exist',
       "link 2" => 'http://magento2.com/url-does-not-exist',
       "link 3" => 'http://magento2.com/url-does-not-exist',
       "link 4" => 'http://magento2.com/url-exist'
   );

   foreach($arr as $key=>$url)
       \Zend_Debug::dump($key.' = '.array_values(get_headers($url))[0]);
   ?>
   ```

   **Result :**

   ```
   string(24) "link 1 = HTTP/1.0 200 OK"

   string(31) "link 2 = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"

   string(31) "link 3 = HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"

   string(24) "link 4 = HTTP/1.0 200 OK"
   ```

Comment: Thanks but that's exactly what I am doing. however in my local server works but In the remote server it doesn't so I've contact server support. thanks.